# How to call MySQL stored procedure by using prepared statements in PHP via mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, prepared-statement

Can someone provide a **working** example in which stored procedure returns a recordset and is called by using prepared statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a good article + examples for  "Using Stored Procedures & MySQLI in PHP 5"

http://www.rvdavid.net/using-stored-procedures-mysqli-in-php-5/

Comment: That on does not use prepared statements.